# Problem defining work function in threadpool (C++)

Tags: c++, threadpool

I've been using the pthreadpool implementation [here](https://github.com/jonhoo/pthread_pool/tree/master) in some previous C code that I wrote, and it's been great.  Now I want to use it in a C++ project, but I'm having some issues.  Here is how I normally set it up in C:

```
void MY_FUNCTION()
{
    struct pool* p = pool_start((void*)theJob, NUM_THREADS);
    for (int a = 0; a < jobCount; a++)
    {
        arguments_t* args = calloc(1, sizeof(*args));
        //assign values to args
        pool_enqueue(p, args, true);
    }
    pool_wait(p);
    pool_end(p);
}

void theJob(arguments_t* args)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Now if I try this in C++ (Visual Studio) I get the error `argument of type "void *" is incompatible with parameter of type "void *(*)(void *)"`.  Well, I tried doing

```
struct pool* p = pool_start((void* (*)(void*))theJob, NUM_THREADS);
```

and it stopped complaining.  When I run the code though, I get the error `LNK2019   unresolved external symbol "void * __cdecl pool_start(void * (__cdecl*)(void *),unsigned int)" (?pool_start@@YAPEAXP6APEAXPEAX@ZI@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl MY_FUNCTION()" (?MY_FUNCTION@@YAXH_K0@Z)`.

Can anyone tell me what I'm supposed to do here?  This isn't really a matter of "unresolved external symbol" but untangling what `void *(*)(void *)` means and how to properly give `pool_start()` what it needs.

Comment: You seem to use pthread_pool.c. You should use pthread_pool.cpp in your project.

Comment: And you need to change `theJob` signature to match the signature expected by `pool_start` so argument can be passed without any casts.

Comment: Maybe ```pool_start``` should be declared as ```extern C```